# express API endpoint works when testing with Talend but will not work on its own from chrome extension

Tags: jquery, express, google-chrome-extension

Using Talend API, a api tester, I am able to successfully use the endpoint written with Express

However, when attempting the same POST request from my chrome extension, I get 404!

```
jQuery.ajax ({
    url: "http://somewhere.com/api/v1/login/",
    type: "POST",
    data:  JSON.stringify({email:"asf@as.com", password: "asdf"),
    contentType: "application/json",
    success: function(data, status){
        alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
    },
    error: function(err){
        console.log(err);
    }
});
```

Above returns 404 while when I send a POST request on my Talend api tester, it returns 200 OK.

Why is there a discrepancy? am I missing something from my jQuery post method?

The 404 returns:

`<!DOCTYPE html>↵<html lang="en">↵<head>↵<meta charset="utf-8">↵<title>Error</title>↵</head>↵<body>↵<pre>Cannot POST /api/v1/login/</pre>↵</body>↵</html>`

I checked the request headers for sending via Talend and via jQuery.

They are EXACTLY the same

server side:

```
// server.js
import express from 'express';
import 'babel-polyfill';
import UserWithDb from './src/usingDB/controller/Users';
import Auth from './src/usingDB/middleware/Auth';

const Reflection = ReflectionWithDB;
const app = express()
var cors = require('cors')
app.use(cors({ origin: true, credentials: true }))

app.use(express.json())

app.options('/api/v1/users/signup', cors())
app.options('/api/v1/users/login', cors())

app.post('/api/v1/users/signup', cors(), UserWithDb.create);
app.post('/api/v1/users/login', cors(), UserWithDb.login);
```

Comment: Can we see the Express code for this route?  Can you show what you used with the API tester?   Basically, you're only showing us ONE request and asking us what's wrong with it without showing us anything about either the server or the request that DOES work.  Not much for us to do with the info we have.

Comment: `Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://myserver/api/v1/login?' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`

Comment: OK, that explains it.  Not sure why you didn't share that before.  Your request is either to a different host than the page you're running the ajax call from or you have something in the request that triggers CORS anyway.  Your server will have to enable CORS requests for the browser to allow this.

Comment: I've enabled cors on my express server using `app.use(cors())`. Now I see a 204 NO CONTENT request being fired followed by 404. I'm really going nuts trying to fix this, CORS is enabled yet I am still getting 404. My origin is set to `null`

Comment: Why are you not sharing your server code?  That's where the issue likely is.

Comment: Also, see this about pre-flight for CORS: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors#enabling-cors-pre-flight.  I don't know if your particular request requires this or not.  You could look at the Network tab in the Chrome debugger to see if the browser is doing an OPTIONS request first.

Comment: it is doing the request first but it is followed by 404

Comment: @jfriend00 I have added server side code

Comment: Is the client doing an OPTIONS request first?  If so, you don't have a handler for that, so it would 404.

Comment: @jfriend00 thats correct. not sure what sort of handlers I would need here

Comment: Look at the link in my earlier comment.  It shows you an example.  `app.options()` for the same URL.

Comment: still getting 404

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your cross origin request is triggering a pre-flight request (sent with the OPTIONS verb) so you need a handler for that in order to allow the browser to do it.  This is probably all you need:

```
app.options('/api/v1/users/signup', cors());
```

As shown in the CORS package [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors#enabling-cors-pre-flight).

There is a list of things that can cause the browser to do a pre-flight.  When doing so, it sends an OPTIONS request to the same URL and needs an appropriate response before it allows the regular request to be sent.

Comment: @user299709 - Getting a 404 on what exactly URL and what request?  Can you show a screenshot from the Chrome network tab that shows exactly what the browser is sending and exactly what the server is responding with.

Comment: I'm getting 404 on POST `/api/v1/users/login` it is at top of my question

Comment: Yeah, but.... Is the 404 actually on the OPTIONS request that the browser does for a pre-flight or on the POST.  We need to see the actual network trace from the network tab in the Chrome debugger.

Comment: I wonder if the `app.options()` handler needs to go before some of your other middleware.  If you're handling things in the middleware, it might not be getting to the `app.options()` handler.

Comment: @user299709 - I think there must be something messed up in the order of your handlers or perhaps you have `cors()` too many places.  Does it get to your `app.post()` handler?  If not, you have to figure out what is stealing the request before that.

Comment: @user299709 - That trace shows the OPTIONS request is working, but the 404 is coming from the POST.

Comment: this is so bizarre. using Talend, it works flawlessly. doing it with jQuery and I get 404'd

Comment: @user299709 - Talend is probably not enforcing CORs or the requests are somehow different.

Comment: I checked the requests and they were exactly the same. no idea how Talend is able to bypass CORS

Comment: @user299709 - CORS is enforced in the client (e.g. the browser).  In this case, it's the browser that wants the server to give it exactly what it wants for CORS.  Talend is apparently choosing to not enforce CORS, it's not really bypassing it.  Is your API public?  If so, I could look at the network trace myself.

Comment: @user299709 - Yeah, that stuff happens.  Glad you got it figured.

Comment: @user299709: don't beat yourself up... that's our job :D